# Aeroplane sitting plan

Tags: code-golf

An airlines company has several planes of the same type.Each plane has a seating capacity of **24 X 3** rows and **8** seats in each row split has shown.

```
1 [a] [b] [c] [d] [e] [f] [g] [h]
2 [a] [b] [c] [d] [e] [f] [g] [h]
3 [a] [b] [c] [d] [e] [f] [g] [h]
```

> If 4 people book-allocate 4 seats in middle row.Else 2 on the right 
>    and 2 on the left.
>
> if 3 people book- id middle section is
>    empty,allocate there continuously.Else go to next row middle section.
>
> if 2 people book-allocate the edge seats.
>
> if 1 person has booked -then allocate whatever free seat available.

eg-
**input** 4
**output**-1c 1d 1e 1f

**input**-3
**output**- 2c 2d 2e

**input**-2
**output**-1a 1b.

Comment: The "split as shown" doesn't show. The allocation rules seem very incomplete. And the scoring can only be one of code-golf, fastest-code (in which can you need to say how measured, and the problem doesn't scale enough for measurement to really be practical in any case), or code-challenge (which means that you have a fairly unique scoring system, and need to explain it in detail).

Comment: This question has potential but it's really confusing at the moment. Plane seats normally have numbers from front to back and letters from left to right. Is this the shortest widebody plane in the world, with only three rows but 8 seats in each? Or does it have "24x3"=72 rows?. From the rules and examples it seems there are aisles in the normal place for an 8 seat wide plane: `ab-cdef-gh` but they are not shown. The allocation rules need improvement too. I think the rule for 4 people is: *allocate 4 seats in middle block. Otherwise 2 on the right and 2 on the left of the aisle.*

Comment: And what do you do if you can't find room for 4, 3 or 2 people by your rules? Error? Allocate them anywhere? What if there is no room left at all? If I have to put 4 people on the outer seats, do they have to be in the same row? Can I assume that I'll never get any other input than one of the four valid numbers?